# Using ng-if with <li> and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have a variable in my `$scope` called `$scope.sortField`.

Based on the value in this variable (`'default'` or otherwise), I'm creating my html view:

```
<li ng-if="sortField != 'default'" ng-repeat="form in forms | filter:filterStates() | orderBy:sortField:isAsc " class="row {{Contextual}}" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">

<li ng-if="sortField == 'default'" ng-repeat="form in forms | filter:filterStates() " class="row {{Contextual}}" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">

<div> 
...
...
<div>

</li>
```

But I'm not able to get it to work. Only the 2nd `<li>` works whereas the 1st one doesn't.

The reason I'm doing the above is because I want to use `orderBy` function in `ng-repeat` only when `$scope.sortField != default`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you comparing two strings? `sortField != default`

Comment: @Aravind yes. $scope.sortField = 'default'; OR it can be some other string.

Comment: what is happening currently both condition fails or ?

Comment: No. The problem is that only the second < li > works. Basically only the < li > which is defined later works.

Comment: the more I look at this, the more confused I become.  instead of having two identical lists and using `ng-if`, why not just set the value of `sortField` to `undefined` when you don't want an `orderBy` applied?  Why do you have to supply a meaningless `'default'` string value?

Comment: @Claies thanks that worked! I always assumed orderBy on undefined will raise error/exception and not go inside the loop at all. so I never thought to use it. but it seems to be ignoring orderBy when I need it to.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't get what you did in filter, just confirmed by the below code snippet, and it works as expected with the `ng-if` and `orderBy`. Let me know if there is any differences.

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.sortField = 'default';
  $scope.forms = [{
      title: 'aaa',
      detail: '4444'
    },
    {
      title: 'bbb',
      detail: '3333'
    },
    {
      title: 'ccc',
      detail: '2222'
    },
    {
      title: 'ddd',
      detail: '1111'
    },
  ];
  $scope.forms2 = [{
      title: 'aaaa',
      detail: 'test detail1'
    },
    {
      title: 'bbbb',
      detail: 'test detail2'
    },
    {
      title: 'cccc',
      detail: 'test detail3'
    },
    {
      title: 'dddd',
      detail: 'test detail4'
    },
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type='text' ng-model="sortField">
  <ui>
    <li ng-if="sortField != 'default'" ng-repeat="form in forms | orderBy:sortField:isAsc " class="row {{Contextual}}" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">{{form.title}} - {{form.detail}}</li>
    <li ng-if="sortField == 'default'" ng-repeat="form in forms2" class="row {{Contextual}}" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">{{form.title}} - {{form.detail}}</li>
  </ui>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would like to solve this. In the snippet below, notice there is a sample dropdown to illustrate the `sortField` selection which is set to `default`. Notice how sorting is not performed (for both `title` and `detail`).

If we change the `sortField` to `title` or `detail`, we'd notice the sorting getting performed. So, it does work how you want it.

See the working snippet:

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.fields = ["default", "title", "detail"];
  $scope.sortField = $scope.fields[0];
  $scope.forms = [{
      title: 'aaa',
      detail: '4444'
    },
    {
      title: 'cbb',
      detail: '7333'
    },
    {
      title: 'bcc',
      detail: '5222'
    },
    {
      title: 'ddd',
      detail: '1111'
    },
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="sortField" name="sortfield" ng-options="field for field in fields">
  </select>
  <ui>
    <li ng-if="sortField != 'default'" ng-repeat="form in forms | orderBy:sortField:isAsc " class="row {{Contextual}}" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">{{form.title}} - {{form.detail}}</li>
    <li ng-if="sortField == 'default'" ng-repeat="form in forms" class="row {{Contextual}}" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">{{form.title}} - {{form.detail}}</li>
  </ui>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `ng-if` condition into a method and have move the condition up one level

```
 <ul ng-if="isDefault()" >
   <li ng-repeat="form in forms | filter:filterStates() | orderBy:sortField:isAsc " class="row {{Contextual}}" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">
</ul>

 <ul ng-if="isDefault()" >
    <li ng-repeat="form in forms | filter:filterStates() " class="row {{Contextual}}" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">
</ul>


$scope.isDefault=function(){
  if($scope.sortField === 'default'){
        return true;
  }else{
       return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: My list has many elements. So will I have to maintain two copies of <ul>'s for this to work?

Comment: yes. how ever only one `<ul>` will be loaded as it is in `ng-if` condition. The reason is for every ng-for item the condition is checked. which causes overhead

Comment: Thanks Aravind. I wish there was a cleaner way in angular to do this without having to maintain two different lists. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: so you are looking for alternative?

Comment: Yeah if there is one that is. Since my list is big, I'm not feeling very good about duplicating it and changing just one line. Do you think I can make it work without duplicating my list?

Comment: I prefer to check condition only once and populate the list and it is needless to have the ng-if inside the <li>. Some time you might end up in out of memory in browser depending on the list size